# C++ Modifying properties from a base class

Tags: c++, inheritance, properties, interface

Okay so this seems so simple and yet it explodes my brain when it doesn't work.
Here's a very simple few classes. (In VC++ btw)

```
class Food
{
protected:
    char maxAmountCarried;
};
class Fruit:Food
{
protected:
     Fruit()
     {
         maxAmountCarried = 8; // Works fine
     }
};
class Watermelon:Fruit
{
protected:
     Watermelon()
     {
          maxAmountCarried = 1; //Food::maxAmountCarried" (declared at line 208) is inaccessible
     }
};
```

So basically, I wanted fruit, by default, to have a max carrying capacity of 8. 
Watermelons are much larger so the capacity is changed to 1. 
However, unfortunately I can't access the property.

It would be so much help if someone could tell me a way to work around this problem.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `interface` is not a valid C++ keyword.

Comment: Nor is leaving off semicolons.

Comment: Woops, sorry! Didn't actually copy and paste the code (this is just an analogy obviously) so I made a couple mistakes =S

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++, when using `class` as the class key to define classes, inheritance is *private* by default. If you want public inheritance, you have to say:

```
class Fruit : public Food { /* ... */ };

class Watermelon : public Fruit { /* ... */ };
```

Otherwise, `Food::maxAmountCarried` becomes *private* in `Fruit` and is not accessible from within `Watermelon`.